# File permissions on docker display "?"

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, chmod, chown

My docker file looks like

```
# https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1

USER root
RUN rm -rf /home/*
RUN adduser -d /home/backup backup

USER backup
RUN cd /home/backup && mkdir -p local/elastic

USER root
RUN chown root:root -R /home/backup
RUN chmod -R a+rX,u+w /home/backup

# Add your elasticsearch plugins setup here
# Example: RUN elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu

USER elasticsearch
```

When i'm connect to my container and run ls -ltr /home/backup i got

```
ls -ltr /home/backup/
ls: cannot access /home/backup/local: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? local
```

I can't acces to /home/backup/local folder, and i dont know why ls display "?" (question marks)

I try to create my directory into /tmp without problem/error i have into /home/backup directory.

Have you any idea ?

Comment: try to exec to container using `-u root`

Comment: It's working with -u option

Comment: But when i start my docker (elk docker) i've the following error message.elasticsearch_1  | org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.repo' (/home/backup/local/elastic) . I must keep repo.path in my elasticsearch configuration

Comment: Try creating the user in your dockerfile before switching to it `USER elasticsearch`. Add `RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash elasticsearch` and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is a wink in the right direction... I hat similar issues with mounting volumes in compose files (file-volumes).

The reason was selinux.
There were two flags ":z" and ":Z".

Try a respective google search:
https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+volume+%3AZ+selinux&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab